# Speech recognizer doesn't work at the first vocal input

Tags: python

I've just connected python to arduino in order to use vocal input. However the main problem is not in arduino but in python

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import time
while True:
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    audio = r.listen(source)

a = (r.recognize_google(audio))
print(a)

if a == 'light on':
    print('ON')

if a == 'switch off':
    print('OFF')
```

Sometimes it returns a NameError: `a` not defined, so `a` is not neither None. It happens only as first input. If it recognizes the first command (eg. switch off) it wouldn't happen in the whole runtime.
While sometimes it crashes while running and gives this error:

```
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 858, in recognize_google
    if not isinstance(actual_result, dict) or len(actual_result.get("alternative", [])) == 0: raise UnknownValueError()
speech_recognition.UnknownValueError
```

I can see it, of course, only if I comment out try...except...

Comment: Yes you shouldn’t have a try/except which only pass - that’s a way to not see all errors, so you won’t know when anything goes wrong. Don’t leave that in any code, it just causes SatackOverflow questions.

Comment: Does it still crash when you remove the arduino/serial code? If so, remove the arduino tag and references to Arduino in your quesiton, because they are irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. @barny yes, it still crashes because of the same UnknownValueError. Is there a way to ignore it (I tried `except ValueError`) and set `a` as None?

Comment: you got any solution for this `r.recognize_google(audio)` ??? i got the same error too.

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    a = (r.recognize_google(audio))
    print(a)
except:
    pass

if a == 'light on':
    arduino.write('H'.encode())
```

if an Exception occurs, `a` will not defined later and the program will crash.

Do e.g.

```
try:
    a = r.recognize_google(audio)
except NameError:
    print('error') # use `traceback`
    a = None
```